# Problem encountered during high school unsaturated fats experiment

Tags: experimental-chemistry, titration, fats, halogenation

To get straight to the point, my chemistry experiment was looking at the amount of unsaturated fats in avocado oil with respect to temperature. I did this by testing for the $\ce{C=O}$ bonds using bromine water. The full procedure is as follows, followed by the actual theory behind the experiment:

1. Pipette out approximately 5 mL of the avocado oil into a boiling tube
   labelled ‘r.t.’ (room temperature) and place the boiling tube on a
   test tube rack.
2. Measure and record the room temperature.
3. Prepare a blank sample in a flask labelled ‘Blank’ by pipetting out
   10mL of bromine water into the flask.
4. Pipette out another 5mL of the oil into another boiling tube
   labelled '$50˚C$’ and heat the boiling tube over a Bunsen burner until
   the oil reaches a temperature of $50˚C$. Place the boiling tube on the
   test tube rack, and repeat this step for the following temperatures
   (˚C): $150, 250, 350.$
5. From the boiling tube labelled ‘r.t.’, measure out approximately
   $0.2g$ of the oil into an iodination flask labelled ‘Test’. Note that the oil does not need to be exactly $0.2g$ as the results will be
   standardized when processing the data, but should still be within
   $0.05g$ of $0.2g$.
6. Close all the curtains and blinds in the room to ensure the room is
   dark. This is due to the fact that the $\ce{Br2}$ in the bromine water is
   susceptible to photo-decomposition, meaning it can be broken down
   into bromide ions by light. Since carbon-carbon double bonds can
   only be broken down by $\ce{Br2}$ molecules and not bromide ions, this
   photo-decomposition will causes inaccuracies in the data.
7. Measure the temperature of the oil in the flask to make sure that it
   is at room temperature value that was recorded in step 2. The oil
   should be at room temperature but if it is higher, wait until the
   temperature lowers to room temperature. If it is lower than room
   temperature by more than $1˚C$, gently heat the flask over a Bunsen
   burner until it reaches room temperature before immediately take the
   flask off heat.
8. Pipette out 10mL of bromine water into the flask and, after
   stoppering the flask, thoroughly shake it to mix the contents.
9. Into the ‘Test’ flask, pipette out 5mL of the 10% $\ce{KI}$ solution before
   stoppering the flask and thoroughly again shaking the solution. The
   colour of the solution should change to a dark brown-red colour. As
   explained in the prior calculations, when the $\ce{KI}$ is added, the
   $\ce{KI}$ dissociates and the $\ce{I-}$ ions oxidise to $\ce{I2}$ while
   reducing the remaining $\ce{Br2}$ molecules to $\ce{Br-}$. The produced
   $\ce{I2}$ will now be titrated against $\ce{Na2S2O3}$. We perform this back
   titration with KI as there is no known direct titration for bromine.
10. Rinse the stopper and the inside of the ‘Test’ flask with 30mL of
    distilled water so that the distilled water flows into the flask.
    This is done in order to ensure that all traces of the solution
    that could be on the stopper or on the inside of the flask, caused
    by the swirling of the flask, enter the solution at the bottom of
    the flask.
11. The solution inside the ‘Test’ flask is then titrated against the
    0.1N $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ until the solution fades to a pale straw-yellow colour
    (take a photo at this point). At this point, most of the $\ce{I2}$ would
    have reacted with the $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ to reduce the $\ce{I2}$ back to iodine
    ions, which are colourless in solution and hence, the colour fades.
    Remember to shake thoroughly.
12. After the solution has faded to a straw-yellow colour, pipette out
    1mL of the starch indicator solution. The colour of the solution
    should now change to a purple-blue colour. Continue titrating with
    the $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ until the colour of the solution turns colourless.
    Record this disappearance of the blue colour as the endpoint of the
    titration. The starch indicator combines with $\ce{I2}$ to form the
    purple-blue colour, hence indicating the presence of $\ce{I2}$. However,
    the $\ce{I2}$ will react preferentially with the $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ which will
    cause the $\ce{I2}$ to be taken from the starch to the $\ce{Na2S2O3}$. The
    starch solution is only added after the solution reaches a straw-yellow
    colour, when most of the $\ce{I2}$ has already reacted, due to the fact
    that if left too long, the $\ce{I2}$ might get permanently bound to the
    starch, which would cause inaccuracies in the data.
13. Empty the flask and stopper and rinse both three times with
    distilled water to eliminate any trace of the solution.
14. Repeat steps 9 - 13 for the ‘Blank’ flask and record the endpoint
    of the titration.
15. Repeat steps 5 - 13 for the oil samples from the remaining seven
    boiling tubes on the test tube rack.

**Some theory on what occurs during the reaction**

This reaction is supposed to happen due to the fact that, even though it is initially non-polar, $\ce{Br2}$ is a very polarizable molecule. When the $\ce{Br2}$ molecule gets close enough to the electrons in the double bond of the alkene, the bonding electrons in the $\ce{Br2}$ molecule repel away from the bond, hence ‘inducing’ a dipole in the bromine molecule. This is shown in Figure 2(a) where the electrons in red repel away from the electrons in blue, causing a dipole moment. This causes the red electrons in the bond to act as a nucleophile and attaches itself to the positively charged bromine atom, which is acting as an electrophile as it wants electrons. At the same time the single bond in the Br2 molecule breaks with the blue electrons going to the negatively charged $\ce{Br}$ atom while a long pair of electrons on the positively charged $\ce{Br}$ atom, shown in purple, bond to one of the carbon atoms in the former double bond. The result, known as a cyclic bromonium ion, is shown in Figure 2(b).

[image: Halogenation]

Note that there is a dipole moment as bromine (electronegativity of 2.96) is slightly more electronegative than carbon (electronegativity of 2.55). This causes the negatively charged bromide ion to attach itself, from the bottom, to one of the carbon atoms, which is acting as an electrophile due to the dipole moment and wants the electrons of the bromide ion. Consequently, on the side that the bromide ion attaches itself, the single bond that is already attached to the bromine at the top breaks away and the bonding electrons go to the bromine atom. Figure 3 shows the full halogenation reaction at the site of the carbon-carbon double bond.

[image]

**So what went wrong?**

After conducting this experiment, the results I got were:

[image: Results]

This shows that, as you increase the temperature, more bromine reacts with the oil, implying that there are more double bonds.

Both my chemistry teacher and I could not figure out what is happening or how the method could be flawed.

Any insights or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: What was the rationale behind the experiment? As iodine or bromine number is a standard parameter in oils - edible or not -, characterization, there should be plenty of informations available, at least to the teacher. Naively I would have expected the opposite. Were the titration steps (all of them) done at room temperature? Also you may think on what would possibly link your results to oxidation. It is possible that oxidation of the fat (that would be peroxide value) is linked to bromine/iodine value but I must think of that as I have no clear picture in a glance.

Comment: The experiment was conducted to gain an experience of conducting an experiment and analysing the results gained. All titration steps were done at room temperature and the oil was left to cool to room temperature before being used. Will try and approach this problem from the oxidation viewpoint, thank you very much for your thoughts @Alchimista.